# Tkinter window has strange styling

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

I have created a new tkinter app and while creating a protoype i realized that my window looks very strange in comparison to the default widgets and windows. I am using python 3.11 and the built in tk version

This is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
# Default imports 

root = Tk()
root.geometry("720x550")
root.overrideredirect(True)


root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=10)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


titleFrame = Frame(root,bd=3, relief=RAISED)
titleFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew",columnspan=2)
titleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

appTitle = Label(titleFrame, text="Sample Tkinter Structuring", font=('Times', '20'))
appTitle.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

appClose = Button(titleFrame, text=" X ", command=root.destroy,anchor="e")
appClose.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="e")

tabs = ttk.Notebook(root)
tabs.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

tab1 = Frame(tabs)
tabs.add(tab1, text="Tab 1")
tab1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
tab1.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

buttonFrame = Frame(tab1,bd=3, relief=RAISED)
buttonFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

shipInfoFrame = Scrollbar(tab1,orient="horizontal")
shipInfoFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

for x in range(5):
    button = Button(buttonFrame, text="Button")
    button.grid(row=x, column=0, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

This is how it looks:

[image: app image]

I expect the default tkinter look. i have looked at tkdocs to see if there where any changes to the ui but couldn't find any.

Edit:
i have also changed widgets to ttk with no result and changed python version.

Comment: Mine is different than your. I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.12.0rc1., Here is an image https://ibb.co/s2f9z6Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i realized that my window looks very strange in comparison to the
> default widgets and windows.

You haven't mentioned about Windows version.

I noticed that your are horizontal for `Scrollbar`. But you are setting wrong grid manager layout.

You're setting `shipInfoFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, ..`. But you're setting  this `column=0`. Should be `column=1

Because you had this `buttonFrame.grid(row=0,...`. Then you set `row = 1`. Then you set this `shipInfoFrame.grid(row=1,...`. Because you set `columnspan=2`.

Don't use wildcard `from tkinter import *`. Use this `import tkinter as tk`. Then `prefix tk`.

I am using `ttk`.

I don't know If this is what you want.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
# Default imports 

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("720x550")
root.overrideredirect(True)


root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=10)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


titleFrame = tk.Frame(root,bd=3, relief=tk.RAISED)
titleFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew",columnspan=2)
titleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

appTitle = ttk.Label(titleFrame, text="Sample Tkinter Structuring", font=('Times', '20'))
appTitle.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

appClose = tk.Button(titleFrame, text=" X ", command=root.destroy,anchor="e")
appClose.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="e")

tabs = ttk.Notebook(root)
tabs.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
tabs.add(tab1, text="Tab 1")
tab1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
tab1.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

buttonFrame = tk.Frame(tab1,bd=3, relief=tk.RAISED)
buttonFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

shipInfoFrame = ttk.Scrollbar(tab1,orient="horizontal")
shipInfoFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

for x in range(5):
    button = ttk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Button")
    button.grid(row=x, column=0, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are not using ttk widgets so you get the old Win98 look. You should avoid `from package import *` for any package and either use `import pkg` or `from pkg import thing1, thing2`.

Your look and feel will be fixed by using `import tkinter.ttk as ttk` and then being explicit about the widget set. So using `titleFrame = ttk.Frame(root)` and `appClose = ttk.Button(titleFrame, label...)` and so on.

Comment: i changed all of the widgets to ttk widgets and got the same result i could share the ss and code if you like but its the same code just the prototype is a little bit updated and all of the widgets are now ttk